# Get Iframe innerHTML when source is from foreign serwer

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, iframe

I have simple iframe, and I want to get iframe innerHTML.
But when source is from foreign server it doesn't work

- browser prevents access because of security reasons.
  I try use `header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');` but it doesn't help
  How can tell my browser or apache server to trust to foreigh server.

  `

  ```
    <button onClick="Show()">Get Iframe Content</button>
    <iframe id="myiframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://not,my.site"></iframe>


    <script>
    function Show(){
    const s = document.getElementById('myiframe');
    alert(s.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);  

    }
    </script>`
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a cross origin page. Iframes and child windows can only be accessed if it's src is `about:blank` or if the **same-origin-policy** applies.

[image: Same Origin Policy]

The only allowed and supported method to communicate between two windows is: [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and the [`window: Message-Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) which provides an easy to use API for communication.